# Prestashop 1.6 Create standalone php file to list products

Tags: list, product, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to create a PHP File in order to display all my products in a XML format.
The PHP file is in the ROOT dir of the PS installation.

Could you please telle how to initialise PS without it adding html and body tags to the pages ?
I also want to get the PublicPrice et the PriceWithoutReduction of the products.

When I try this code I get a Fatal Error.
The URL : http://www.topludo.fr/xml_guide.php

Thanks for advance.

Pierre.

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
header("Content-Type:application/xml");
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config/config.inc.php');
Context::getContext()->shop->setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . chr(10);
echo '<catalogue lang="FR" date="' . date('Y-m-d H:i') . '" GMT="+1" version="2.0">' . chr(10);

$id_lang = 1;
$front = false;

// Requête identifiant les produits disponibles dans le catalogue
echo $sql = 'SELECT p.*, pl.* , m.`name` AS manufacturer_name FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p   '.
                ' LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl ON (p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`)'.
                ' LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'manufacturer` m ON (m.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer`)'.
                ' WHERE pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.' ORDER BY name ASC';
$rq = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($sql);

foreach ($rq as &$row)
    $row = Product::getTaxesInformations($row);

$products_query = $rq;
$product_num = 0;

foreach($products_query as $key => $products) {
    $product = new Product($products['id_product']);
    $product_num++;

    $categories = Product::getProductCategoriesFull($product->id, $id_lang);
    $category = end($categories); 

    //$reducPrice = Product::getPriceStatic($products['id_product'], true, null, 0);
    echo $product->getPublicPrice();
    $fullPrice = ceil($product->getPriceWithoutReduct());

    if ($fullPrice < $reducPrice) {
        $discount_price = '';
        $regular_price = $fullPrice;
        $sale = 0;
    } else {
        $discount_price = $reducPrice;
        $regular_price = $fullPrice;
        $sale = 2; 
    }

    $cover_id = $product->getCover($product->id); // L'image du produit
    $link = new Link();
    $cover_image_link = $link->getImageLink('large-default', $cover_id['id_image']);
    $sp = SpecificPrice::getByProductId($product->id); // Pour les dates de reduc
    $manufacturer = Manufacturer::getNameById($product->id_manufacturer); // Le fabricant

    echo '<product place="' . $product_num . '">' . "\n";
    echo '<merchant_category><![CDATA[' . $category['name'] . ']]></merchant_category>' . chr(10);
    echo '<offer_id><![CDATA[' . $product->id . ']]></offer_id>' . chr(10);
    echo '<name><![CDATA[' . $product->name[1] . ']]></name>' . chr(10);
    echo '<description><![CDATA[' . substr(strip_tags(str_replace(array('<BR>', '<br>'), "</P>\n<P>", html_entity_decode($products['description']))), 0, 245) . '...]]></description>' . chr(10);
    echo '<regular_price currency="EUR">' . $regular_price . '</regular_price>' . chr(10);
    echo '<product_url><![CDATA[' . $product->getLink() . ']]></product_url>' . chr(10);
    echo '<image_url><![CDATA[' . $cover_image_link . ']]></image_url>' . chr(10);
    echo '<discount_price currency="EUR">' . $discount_price . '</discount_price>' . chr(10);
    echo '<price_discounted_from><![CDATA[' . substr($sp[0]['from'], 0, 16) . ']]></price_discounted_from>' . chr(10);
    echo '<price_discounted_until><![CDATA[' . substr($sp[0]['to'], 0, 16) . ']]></price_discounted_until>' . chr(10);
    echo '<sales>' . $sale . '</sales>' . chr(10);
    echo '<delivery currency="EUR">FR;0;</delivery>' . chr(10);
    echo '<manufacter>'.''.'</manufacter>' . chr(10);
    echo '<brand><![CDATA[' . $manufacturer . ']]></brand>' . chr(10);
    echo '<model_number><![CDATA[' . $product->reference . ']]></model_number>' . chr(10);
    echo '<manufacturer_product_id><![CDATA[]]></manufacturer_product_id>' . chr(10);
    echo '<ean13>'.$product->ean13.'</ean13>' . chr(10);
    echo '<guarantee unit="year">1</guarantee>' . chr(10);
    echo '<used>0</used>' . chr(10);
    echo '<used_condition><![CDATA[]]></used_condition>' . chr(10);
    echo '<update_date><![CDATA[' . substr($product->date_upd, 0, 16) . ']]></update_date>' . chr(10);
    echo '<promo_text><![CDATA[]]></promo_text>' . chr(10);
    echo '<offer_valid_from><![CDATA[' . substr($sp[0]['from'], 0, 16) . ']]></offer_valid_from>' . chr(10);
    echo '<offer_valid_until><![CDATA[' . substr($sp[0]['to'], 0, 16) . ']]></offer_valid_until>' . chr(10);
    echo '<size unit="cm"></size>' . chr(10);
    echo '<weight unit="kg">0.00</weight>' . chr(10);
    echo '<color><![CDATA[]]></color>' . chr(10);
    echo '</product>';

    flush();
}

echo '</catalogue>';
```

Answer (score 2):

To initialize PrestaShop use:

```
require_once __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.inc.php';
require_once __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'init.php';
```

Instead of using header to set your content type to xml and then `echo` your tags, I recommend using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). It's much easier to manipulate your XML and it will result in easier to read code. After you create your `SimpleXMLElement` and add to it all your product properties as children, you can use `asXML` method to get the XML string or you can save the XML to a file by passing a file name argument to `asXML`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm generating a file on the disk with SimpleXML and it works fine! ;)